# How to set a custom frequency trigger on google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm a new user for Google apps script, I meet a question recently.
In Google apps script, I want to set a trigger to run the app on 9:00AM every day. But I can only set a trigger by Trigger-Add a trigger, set a trigger 9:00-10:100 AM every day,But I found that it run my program about 9:30 every day. 
So my question is how set a trigger on 9:00 AM every day?
Thank you very much..

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the "Add a trigger" feature will only let you set triggers within this one hour range.

You can, however, set a narrower time range if you create your trigger programmatically (using the ClockTriggerBuilder class). It'll still have a thirty minute range, though: the app run will run at 9am plus or minus 15 minutes. Is that close enough for you or do you need it to run at 9am sharp?

It would go like this:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('YourFunction')
  .timeBased()
  .everyDays(1)
  .atHour(9)
  .create();
```

[Here you can find more information](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder)

Comment: Thank you, and I wish it will run at 9am sharp... plus and minus 5 minutes is OK. So do you think it's not possible? And I don't know how to use ClockTriggerBuilder class, do you have a good example for me?

Comment: I added an example to my answer, plus a link to GoogleDevelopers. I'm afraid the plus and minus 15 minutes range is as precise as it gets.

Comment: OK,I will test it , and for the code. should I need add it to my function onOpen() ?

Comment: No. If you do that, you'll create a new trigger every time you open your document. Create a separate function just to create the trigger, run it once and be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

if it must run precisely at a given time, your only option is to create a trigger that runs every minute, and first thing checks if its the correct time to run.

to check if its time, save the last run time in a script property and compare with the current time.

all other methods will give you a delay of a few minutes, even if you set the trigger to run at a specific time.

Comment: complementary info : if you're afraid of exceeding some limit (max processing time or whatever) just set one trigger at 8 AM that creates an "every minute trigger" and remove it when you're done, keeping only the 8 AM one... simple & easy

Comment: thats a good idea but in this case it wont run over limits. just checking every minute for a script property consumes maybe 5 seconds per trigger.