# Google Script Trigger Every 30 Days

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm interested in having my functions be triggered every 30 days. The closest I can find within Google is the once a month option, but that'll vary away from 30 days due to February and the months with 31 days.

Does anyone have any advice on how I could get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a trigger on 9:00 AM every day on google apps script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469813/how-to-set-a-trigger-on-900-am-every-day-on-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 0):

Trigger this every day. It will run the first time then eventually run 30 days later etc.

```
// trigger this function every day
function myFunction() {

  var lastRunDate = new Date(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("lastRunDate"));
  var thirtyDaysAgo = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-30));

  if (lastRunDate > thirtyDaysAgo) {
    return; //exit because it's not yet been 30 days since last run
  } else {
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("lastRunDate", new Date()); 
  }

  // do you work here

}
```